# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with NSOPERATION and ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I have an application that works fine in an older project (that doesn't use ARC and was written against in Xcode 4.0 with iOS 4.2.

I am trying to port this application over to use ARC and storyboard with Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5.

I have got everything ported over and fixed all the error caused by retaining, releasing, deallocing, etc.  The project builds fine now.  I also rebuilt my Core Data model in the new project and rebuild my model subclasses.

Where the error happens is when I try to parse an XML file in a background thread.  The file is local to the project.  I NSLog the initializer for each NSOperation class that does the parsing (there are four of them).  I am getting to that point of the application, the error occurs when I add the operations to the queue.

Here is my code in the AppDelegate that starts the Operations:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ACHPhonebook.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;

@synthesize parseQueue;
@synthesize parseOpAD, parseOpEK, parseOpLR, parseOpSZ;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ACHPhonebook" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    [request setEntity:entity];    

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSUInteger count = [self.managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    NSLog(@"total CD count = %d", count);

    if(
       getenv("NSZombieEnabled") || getenv("NSAutoreleaseFreedObjectCheckEnabled")
       ) {
        NSLog(@"NSZombieEnabled/NSAutoreleaseFreedObjectCheckEnabled enabled!");
    }

    if (count == 0) {
        // Purge the DB
        [ACHPhonebook purgePhoneBook:self.managedObjectContext];

        // NSLog(@"Just purged the phonebook");

        // Set up the NSOperation Queue for the parsing
        parseQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

        // Make an operation to import the phonebook    
        //[self setParseOp:[[ParseOperation alloc] initAndStartParse]]; 
        [self setParseOpAD:[[ParseOperationA_D alloc] initAndStartParse]];
        [self setParseOpEK:[[ParseOperationE_K alloc] initAndStartParse]];
        [self setParseOpLR:[[ParseOperationL_R alloc] initAndStartParse]];
        [self setParseOpSZ:[[ParseOperationS_Z alloc] initAndStartParse]];

        // [parseQueue addOperation:parseOp];

        NSArray *opArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:parseOpAD, parseOpEK, parseOpLR, parseOpSZ, nil];

        [parseQueue addOperations:opArray waitUntilFinished:NO];
    }


//    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
//    // Override point for customization after application launch.
//    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
//    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Here is one of the NSOperation Classes (they are all the same, just working on different files to help speed up the initial loading of 6000 records.

```
#import "ParseOperationA-D.h"
#import "ACHPhonebook.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "TBXML.h"

@implementation ParseOperationA_D

- (id)initAndStartParse
{
    NSLog(@"ParseOperation init");

    // [self parsePhonebook];

    return self;

}

- (void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    id appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    // Merge changes into the main context on the main thread
   [mainContext performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:)  
                                withObject:notification
                                waitUntilDone:NO];

    // NSLog(@"Merged Changes");
}

// the main function for this NSOperation, to start the parsing
- (void)main {

    id appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *ctx = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [ctx setUndoManager:nil];
    [ctx setPersistentStoreCoordinator: [appDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator]];

    // Register context with the notification center
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]; 
    [nc addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(mergeChanges:) 
               name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
             object:ctx];

    NSUInteger x = 1;

    TBXML *tbxml = [[TBXML alloc] initWithXMLFile:@"achcentral_aTOd.xml"];

    // Get root element
    TBXMLElement * root = tbxml.rootXMLElement;

    // if root element is valid
    if (root) {

        NSError *error = nil;

        TBXMLElement *thisPBE = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"PhoneBookResults" parentElement:root];

        while (thisPBE != nil) {

            // Set up the Insert command
            ACHPhonebook * xmlPBE = (ACHPhonebook *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ACHPhonebook" inManagedObjectContext:ctx];

            // Set all the field values from the XML record

            //            TBXMLElement *elName = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"Name" parentElement:thisPBE];
            //            if (elName != nil) {
            //                [xmlPBE setName:[TBXML textForElement:elName]];
            //            }

            TBXMLElement *elTitle = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"title" parentElement:thisPBE];
            if (elTitle != nil) {
                [xmlPBE setTitle:[TBXML textForElement:elTitle]];
            }

            TBXMLElement *elDept = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"department" parentElement:thisPBE];
            if (elDept != nil) {
                // obtain the text from the description element
                [xmlPBE setDepartment:[TBXML textForElement:elDept]];
            }

            TBXMLElement *elExt = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"phone" parentElement:thisPBE];
            if (elExt != nil) {
                [xmlPBE setExt:[TBXML textForElement:elExt]];
            }

            TBXMLElement *elPager = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"pager" parentElement:thisPBE];
            if (elPager != nil) {
                [xmlPBE setPager:[TBXML textForElement:elPager]];
            }

            TBXMLElement *elEmailAddress = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"emailaddress" parentElement:thisPBE];
            if (elEmailAddress != nil) {
                [xmlPBE setEmailAddress:[TBXML textForElement:elEmailAddress]];
            }

            //            TBXMLElement *elNetworkID = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"NetworkID" parentElement:thisPBE];
            //            if (elNetworkID != nil) {
            //                [xmlPBE setNetworkid:[TBXML textForElement:elNetworkID]];
            //            }

            TBXMLElement *elLastName = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"lastName" parentElement:thisPBE];
            if (elLastName != nil) {
                [xmlPBE setLastName:[TBXML textForElement:elLastName]];
            }

            TBXMLElement *elFirstName = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"firstName" parentElement:thisPBE];
            if (elFirstName != nil) {
                [xmlPBE setFirstName:[TBXML textForElement:elFirstName]];
            }

            if (elFirstName != nil && elLastName !=nil) {
                // Make the name field from the first and last names
                NSString *fullName = [[TBXML textForElement:elFirstName] stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@",[TBXML textForElement:elLastName]];
                [xmlPBE setName:fullName];
            }

            TBXMLElement *elPicLoc = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"picFileName" parentElement:thisPBE];
            if (elPicLoc != nil) {
                if (![[TBXML textForElement:elPicLoc] isEqualToString:@""])
                {
                    [xmlPBE setPicloc:[TBXML textForElement:elPicLoc]];

                    NSString *picFilePath = @"https://secure.archildrens.org/insite/badgepics/adbadgepics/";

                    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[picFilePath 
                                        stringByAppendingString:xmlPBE.picloc]];
                    NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: url];
                    if (!imageData)
                    {
                        // The image filename was stored but didn't exist
                        NSString *achImage = 
                        [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ach" ofType:@"png"]; 
                        imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:achImage];
                    }

                    [xmlPBE setPicture:imageData];

                }
            }

            if (x % 50 == 0) {
                // Get ready to save the context
                error = nil;
                // Save the context.
                if (![ctx save:&error])
                {
                    NSLog(@"loadPhoneBook error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                    abort();
                }

                // Clear out the scratchpad
                [ctx reset];

                //NSLog(@"Got 10");
            }
            // Find the next XML record (this will end the while loop when we reach the end)
            thisPBE = [TBXML nextSiblingNamed:@"PhoneBookResults" searchFromElement:thisPBE];

            // Increment the counter
            x++;

        } // while ...

        if ([ctx hasChanges]) {

            // NSUInteger *left = [[ctx insertedObjects] count];
            error = nil;
            // Save the context.
            if (![ctx save:&error])
            {
                NSLog(@"loadPhoneBook error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                abort();
            }

            // Clear out the scratchpad
            [ctx reset];

            NSLog(@"Got the last ones, %d", x);
        }

    }
}

@end
```

I have tried enabling `NSZombies` and still can't see what is going on.  It always breaks with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error on the

```
[parseQueue addOperations:opArray waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

line in the `AppDelegate`, this was my first attempt at multithreading in an iOS app.  Like I said before, I have a version that runs that was built against an older version of the SDK and it still runs.  This may be (and probably is) something really simple that I am overlooking...

Comment: Your `initAndStartParse` method isn't calling `self = [super init];`. I don't think you're instantiating the NSOperation subclasses correctly.

Comment: This was exactly the problem.  Once I fixed that the project compiled without error and ran fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set [MallocStackLogging](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MallocStackLogging), [guard malloc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html), and (you may have already done this one) [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled) in the debugger.  Then, when your App crashes, type this in the gdb console:

```
(gdb) info malloc-history 0x543216
```

Replace `0x543216` with the address of the object that caused the crash, and you will get a much more useful stack trace and it should help you pinpoint the exact line in your code that is causing the problem.

[See this article for more detailed instructions.](http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone)

Comment: See my comment about sho's comment above.  While this wasn't solved by using Zombies and malloc, this answer has helped me find two other issues since then :)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using NSOperations, having you tried self performSelectorInBackground:withObject:?

Comment: I have not.  I thought using NSOperations was the preferred way of creating background threads that did lots of work.  Can you explain why this method would be better than using NSOperations and NSOperationQueue?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935007/difference-between-performselectorinbackground-and-nsoperation-subclass

Comment: That doesn't go into why I shouldn't be using NSOperations (which is what the example applications that I have seen on Apple's Dev site use).

Comment: Performance-wise, the difference between threading with NSOperations and performSelectorInBackground is minimal. I would try performSelectorInBackground, and if that doesn't crash, I would call it better.

Comment: That still doesn't give me any idea of what the problem is.  I really want to solve the problem and not just band-aid it.  Thanks though.